Translate DPI setting from old to new mouse
I had a Razer Deathadder 2013, which apparently runs @ max 6400 DPI.
I bought a new Razer Deathadder v3 PRO, which can do between 100 and 30k.
I set it up at 6400 but it is way more sensitive. I actually get a more exact match at 1200 DPI.

How can I get the necessary info to calculate/get the DPI I should set on the new mouse?

It is possible that my previous mouse was not at 6400, or that other settings my interfer. I'm testing on Windows, not on a game or anything so far.

What I want : have the same sensitivity from one mouse to another by adjusting the DPI setting accordingly.

Other settings that could interfer : I don't know, maybe from one mouse processor to another it can be more or less sensitive at the same DPI setting.

As a same DPI setting lead to different "sensitivity", I can only deduce that other "thing" have an impact

Don't add comments to a question -- instead, edit the question to make a coherent whole.

I don't know what to add @DrMoishePippik : I stated the issue ("way more sensitive"), and the question ("calculate the DPI"). I also stated reflection I had on the issue (last paragraph.) If you feel some things needs to be added, do so, you're allowed to do that. On my side I (honestly) don't see what needs to be added.

As the same DPI feels differently to you I believe the only way you can determine what DPI you should use is through trial and error.

It is possible that the previous mouse was not set to exactly 6400.  It is also possible that due to different surfaces on the mouse, the friction is different and the movement therefore is lightly different.
A mouse, inherently, is not an accurate device.  It works because of continuous feedback with the persons eyes and hand.
You just have to set it the best you can.
